# Опубликован ответ к вопросу, закрытому как дубликат

Tags: дефект, закрытие-вопросов, дубликаты, временная-шкала

В соответствии с [временной шкалой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/618410/timeline) вопрос был закрыт в 15:26, а затем был опубликован ответ в 15:30 (позже).

Кнопки «Отправьте ваш ответ»  я не вижу, поэтому новые ответы вроде бы не должны больше добавляться.

Comment: Вот только что [объявил конкурс на вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617713/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-one-to-zero-or-one-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81-one-to-many) и меня в браузере была надпись 'конкурс на вопрос можно будет объявить 6 минут назад'. Совпадение? Может время на сервере сбилось?

Comment: @AK дежавю, как в The Matrix :)

Comment: Если Вы ещё этого не сделали, я бы рекомендовал задать подобный вопрос на Meta.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Можно руками раздисейблить кнопку и запостить ответ (если ты его писал, когда вопрос закрыли). Но вот запостить ответ, если ты перешёл на вопрос после закрытия, не получается.

Comment: Не ясно что это значит. Если сервер считает что вопрос закрыт, то никакие манипуляции на клиенте не должны позволять новые ответы добавлять.

Comment: @jfs, видимо, сервер считает что-то другое. Возможно, это сделано намеренно, чтобы недописанный ответ не приходилось выкидывать.

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь сказать? timeline с сервера возвращается. timeline говорит что ответ опубликован после закрытия. В этом баг и состоит.

Comment: Если вопрос закрывают в процессе написания ответа, то вываливается баннер. Недавно с Николаем [фиксили подобный](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4364/176217).

Comment: @jfs, это не баг, а фича. Оставь в покое.