# Как получить доступ к временной шкале?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, ответы, временная-шкала

Из вопроса «[Опубликован ответ к вопросу, закрытому как дубликат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4605/208074)» я узнал о существовании *временно́й шкалы*, хранящей в себе историю действий с определённым вопросом или ответом.

Она находится по адресу `ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/идентификатор/timeline`. Вот её [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/348366/timeline) для произвольного вопроса с короткой историей:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** как можно получить доступ к этому разделу из пользовательского интерфейса StackOverflow на русском?

Comment: На метамете написано что к этому таймлайну - по ходу никак. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/list-of-unlinked-pages-on-stack-exchange-sites
Возможно у 10к+ какая-нибудь кнопочка но она ведет немного к другому таймлайну скорее всего

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, неа, ручками. Сначала жмёшь history, если есть, потому переписываешь на timeline.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму у модераторов есть отдельной кнопочкой. Как-то Nofate рассказывал. Но там другой адрес получается.

Comment: P.S. На мете уже как минимум [7 вопросов, упоминающих временную шкалу](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0+is%3Aq).

Comment: @alexolut ещё рано создавать для них отдельную метку?

Comment: @AK оу ... действительно. Метка же есть. И вроде как я её создавал, правда без описания :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На текущий момент только в ручном режиме, путём изменения URL в строке браузера по указанному шаблону. Но [может быть кое-что изменится](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180594/339911), т.к. текущий статус заявки - "отложено".

У модераторов есть более удобный доступ, [если не врут](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=34413961#34413961) :)

Comment: `более удобный доступ` — по вашей ссылке это назвали *«filtered version of the moderator timeline»*. В свою очередь, то, что доступно всем, обозвали как *«old timeline experiment»*.

Comment: @Arhad "filtered version of the moderator timeline" это текущая версия, которую Вы можете видеть. Я так понимаю, что раньше она выглядела иначе ("old timeline experiment") и не пользовалась спросом.