# Ищете ли вы дубликаты вопроса перед написанием ответа?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, ответы, дубликаты

По некоторым повторяющимся вопросам (вроде `NullPointerException`) легко понять, что уже есть вопрос-дубликат.

Но, как правило, лично я перед ответом на вопрос не лезу искать дубликаты. Как следствие, периодически после моего ответа кто-то отмечает вопрос как дубликат.

Вот интересно, как поступают другие. Пытаетесь ли вы найти дубликат вопроса перед ответом? И вообще, следует ли так делать?

Comment: Не ищу. Если подозреваю, что это точно дубликат, то не отвечаю

Comment: Если вопрос вызывает чувство вида «даладна, неужели это до сих пор никто не спрашивал?», то ищу

Answer (score 7):

Если написание ответа занимает менее минуты - обычно просто пишу ответ.

Если точно знаю, что дубликат есть, закрываю как дубликат.

Если не знаю, то не ищу, даже если предполагаю, что он есть.

Comment: А точно знать можно только про функции обратного вызова))

Comment: @vp_arth, и потерю контекста :)

Comment: @vp_arth, я предпочитаю специально заготовленные faq вопросы, а их довольно мало.

Answer (score 7):

### Дубликаты — это плохо или хорошо?

Вообще помните, что дубликаты, с точки зрения базы знаний, — это почти всегда хорошо, так как люди могут по-разному формулировать свои мысли и соответственно, чем больше людей придут с поисковиков на дубликаты, тем больше внимания получит оригинальный вопрос и, соответственно больше людей, возможно, решат свои проблемы.

Бывают случаи, когда у дубликатов в разы или даже на порядки больше плюсов и просмотров. И соответственно у ответов на них больше плюсов и внимания. Также качество этих ответов может быть выше, чем у ответов на оригинальный вопрос. Что на мой взгляд, лишь подтверждать отсутствие крамолы в самом факте дублирования.

### Стоит ли искать подобные вопросы или точные дубликаты?

Это точно стоит делать, если вы автор вопроса (подходит также и для самоответов). Но если вы просто отвечающий, то это необязательно.

- Если вы не знаете был ли такой вопрос или его не удалось найти, то можно просто написать ответ. Если вопрос закроют как дубликат, то у вас будет в какой-то мере "монополия на плюсики".
- Если вы знаете, что такой вопрос всё-таки был раннее задан, то, может быть, и стоит написать ответ. *Причина этого в том, что точные дубликаты встречаются, по моему опыту, крайне редко.* Часто в вопросе можно встретить новые нюансы или запросы, которые было бы необходимо прояснить, но которые будут неуместны в ответе к оригинальному вопросу. Также можно было бы сослаться на некий "эталонный ответ", если он есть и добавить нюансов в ответе.

### Стоит ли на поиски дубликатов тратить много времени?

Я лично считаю, что не стоит убивать много времени на поиск дубликатов. Если в гугле и SO не найден подобный вопрос в течение нескольких минут, то можно попробовать писать. Раз вы так и не увидели дубликатов, то пусть само сообщество решит был ли ранее задан такой вопрос.

---

В самом крайнем случае, ответ можно будет удалить, если вы не видете в нём никакой пользы.  Преград на удаление бесполезных ответов нет никаких, в отличие от вопросов, на которые уже дали какие-нибудь ответы.

Comment: *Стоит ли искать подобные вопросы или точные дубликаты?* Вроде бы **Suvitruf** говорит об отвечающих, а этот пункт (как, впрочем, и следующий) - явно о вопрошающих...

Comment: @Akina Да, вы правы, спасибо. Я почему-то это упустил при написании ответа.

Comment: @Akina Переписал ответ.

Answer (score 6):

Поначалу - искал.

Как минимум в половине (а скорее всего - чаще) случаев находящиеся темы реально близки, но слегка отличаются, и вроде бы подходящий ответ надо слегка модифицировать. Как результат - если инициировать закрытие вопроса как дубликата, это пройдёт, а квалификация автора на самом деле низка настолько, что её не хватит на нужную корректировку, получится не очень хорошо.

Нередко находится несколько достаточно близких вопросов. В этом случае на тебя ещё падает неблагодарная работа просмотреть такие вопросы, просмотреть ответы (даже включая не отмеченные как решение), и оценить в комплексе, какой из вопросов наиболее разумно указать как дублирующий. А с учётом того, что автор не всегда спрашивает точно то, что хочет спросить - легко и не угадать.

В общем, для себя решил, что это - пустое. И не ищу, а пишу ответ, если вопрос интересен или хотя бы не совершенно тривиален. Исключение - когда точно знаю, что такой вопрос-дубликат, причём дубликат практически дословный, был совсем недавно (да, бывало...).

Если я решил предложить закрыть вопрос, а кто-то уже предложил закрытие вопроса как дубликата - обязательно просматриваю предложенный вопрос-дубликат и решение в нём. Если считаю, что это не точный дубликат - голосую за закрытие по иной (которую хотел указать изначально) причине.

Кстати... если, к примеру, я всё же озаботился поиском и нашёл "почти дубликат", а самому точный ответ писать явно лень, то что лучше - предложить закрытие как дубликат, или просто дать ссылку на такой вопрос-недодубликат в комментарии?

Comment: Насчёт последнего вопроса: можно в любом случае спросить в комментариях мнение ТС: "Вы согласны с тем, что ваш вопрос идентичен вопросу X? Если нет, то чем ваш отличается?" И тут в зависимости от ответа ТС исходить. Может, он даже добровольно согласится, что это дубликат и вам "спасибо" скажет. Даже голоса за закрытие всегда можно отзывать или, в крайнем случае, потом инициировать переоткрытие. Поэтому не вижу смысла стесняться их применять.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4971/178988

Comment: Насчёт последнего вопроса: обычно в этом случае не закрывая приводят ссылку предваряя её словами "смежный вопрос", "похожий вопрос" или "аналогичный". В блоке ссылок справа он начинает светиться как связанный - очень удобно.

Answer (score 6):

Если помню, что уже видел - да, ищу. Если нахожу быстро - помечаю, нет - значит, не сложилось...

Беда еще в том, что абсолютно точных дубликатов не бывает. Та же классика `while(!feof(f))` отвечена уже много раз, но вопрос-то каждый раз иной - то "почему не читает", то "лишняя запись", то "помогите найти ошибку"... Ну и как тут дубли помечать?...

Comment: Вот поэтому и надо эталонные вопросы делать.

Comment: @Qwertiy В эту игру я не игрец :) - несколько раз пробовал, получал такой шквал, мягко скажем, критики (чего никогда не было за точно такие же ответы на чужие вопросы), что всегда заканчивалось удалением и обещанием себе больше так не делать...

Comment: Что-то странно. У меня всегда хорошо заканчивалось :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Вот вы их и пишите :)

Comment: Так я и пишу :)

Answer (score 0):

Отвечать на вопрос выгоднее, чем отмечать дубликатом - за принятый/заплюсованный ответ дадут репутацию, а за дубликат - нет. Но есть риск, что пока пишешь ответ, вопрос закроют.

Я обычно указываю как дубликат, если я уже давал ответ на такой вопрос, и даю ссылку на свой ответ. Этакая "конкурентная борьба" - мне могут плюсануть старый ответ и не надо тратить время и силы на написание. Правда я не помню, чтобы эта тактика хоть раз сработала за 4 года ;)

Могу указать дубликат, если его легко найти. Через некоторое время вырабатывается некая интуиция, определить по вопросу, можно ли найти дубликат секунд за пять. Соответственно, если находится быстро, могу отметить.

Comment: "Но есть риск" - если начали писать, то ответ засабмитить дадут.

Comment: Да? Спасибо, не знал про такое, поэтому всегда воспринимал как "риск".

Comment: @AK с каких пор?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Всегда так было. Я сам лично воспользовался как-то этим лайфхаком на мете.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, только надо через браузерные devtools кнопку раздисейблить. Ну и вроде лимит в 3 часа - потом уже нельзя. И если вкладку в браузере закрывал, то тоже вряд ли получится. Точнее, мобильное приложение точно позволяет, значит технически можно, но лично у меня так отправить не получалось с сайта. PS: А ещё можно сначала ответить, а потом задубликатить.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4605/178988